# Modify query to use INSERT INTO

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I have developed a pretty complicated query, and now have hard time modifying it to use INSERT INTO statement.

The query (VS syntax):

```
           @"SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID, " +
           " @todaysDate " +
           " AS ScanningTime " +
           " FROM (((Student s " +
           " LEFT JOIN [CourseID-ModuleID] cm ON s.CourseID = cm.CourseID) " +
           " LEFT JOIN [ModuleID-SessionID] ms ON cm.ModuleID = ms.ModuleID) " +
           " LEFT JOIN [Session] se ON ms.SessionID = se.SessionID) " +
           " WHERE s.TagID = @tagNo " +
           " AND se.SessionDate = cast(getdate() as date) " +
           " AND se.SessionTimeStart <= @Plus30Min " +
           " AND se.SessionTimeEnd >= @Plus30Min ";
```

The query runs perfectly, but I would like to place the result of the query into the empty table `Attendance`, which already exists in the DB.

```
Attendance table data types

TagID - int
SessionID - varchar
ScanningTime - datetime.
```

Please note that data types for Attendance table match with other tables data types.

I have tried placing "INSERT INTO Attendance (s.TagID, se.SessionID, ScanningTime)" just before the SELECT statement, but then my query does not produce any results.

What is a proper way to modify my query to include INSERT INTO statement? Thanks

**EDIT:**

All your answers and suggestions where very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Try prepending with what you have _without the qualifiers_ that make no sense in the Attendance table; `INSERT INTO Attendance (TagID, SessionID, ScanningTime) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `(s.TagID, se.SessionID, ScanningTime)` and just add `INSERT INTO Attendance` before your select

```
@"INSERT INTO Attendance
 SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID, "
 etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the below Code :

```
@"INSERT INTO Attendance(
   TagID , 
   SessionID,
   ScanningTime )
SELECT s.TagID, se.SessionID, " +
           " @todaysDate " +
           " AS ScanningTime " +
           " FROM (((Student s " +
           " LEFT JOIN [CourseID-ModuleID] cm ON s.CourseID = cm.CourseID) " +
           " LEFT JOIN [ModuleID-SessionID] ms ON cm.ModuleID = ms.ModuleID) " +
           " LEFT JOIN [Session] se ON ms.SessionID = se.SessionID) " +
           " WHERE s.TagID = @tagNo " +
           " AND se.SessionDate = cast(getdate() as date) " +
           " AND se.SessionTimeStart <= @Plus30Min " +
           " AND se.SessionTimeEnd >= @Plus30Min ";
```